# Restrict the number of options on a quick filter with single value (list) type on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Suppose a dimension has five items:

```
cars
buses
airplanes
bicycles
boats
```

and I select the quick filter to be single value (list). I want to be able to select only between cars, buses and bicycles. How can I restrict the number of options on a quick filter with a single value (list) on Tableau?

Comment: Tableau doesn't support this functionality in quick filters, but you can easily get the exact same functionality by creating a string parameter with a list of values (cars, buses, bicycles) and then filtering based on the parameter's value.

Comment: How can I filter using a parameter? I can only filter integer values.

Comment: I was wrong -- you can do it with quick filters. See below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you can restrict the number of options on a quick filter. Drag the dimension into the filters pane, right click on it, and select filter. Make sure  just the ones you want to be available are selected, and click OK.

Now, create a copy of the dimension. Drag the copy to the filters pane, where the original already is. Right click, filter, and then find the tiny "Shower fewer values" button on the top right of the general tab. Select all of the boxes, which should be the ones you want.

Now, right click on the original dimension you added as a filter (not the copy). Show quick filter, and there should only be the appropriate filter options.

Comment: Did that a few seconds ago! Thanks anyway, accepting because it is the correct answer.

Comment: Also make sure the quick filter is set to "show only relevant values" in this case